# jspm for install angular return "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:..\AppData\Local\.jspm\packages\npm\@angular\core@8.2.9\bundles' "

Tags: node.js, angular, jspm

hope everybody is in good willing , please any help will be appreciated ,,,

I'm using jspm to install angular,, but I return this error continously "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\AbduRahman\AppData\Local.jspm\packages\npm@angular\core@8.2.9\bundles' "
what can I do to solve or go arround this issue.
thanks again.

Comment: Run your command line with the admin rights

Comment: close vs code, any open folders, any cmd prompts and try again. If that fails, go into the bundles folder, delete every sub-directory manually, then delete the parent folder.  You might have to go several nested folders deep.

Comment: I've tried all the step you mentioned, unfortunately failed, and the bundles folder is already empty- @pixelbits